# Error while accessing an associative array

Tags: templating, array

Here is the code:

```
{% if entry_name not in data and entry_total > 0 %}
    {% set data = data|merge({ (entry_name) : entry_total }) %}
{% else %}
    {% set data.entry_name = 10 %}
{% endif %}
```

Twig throws an error on the statement following `else` condition.  `Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected).` How can I set the value of a particular element of this associative array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a pretty way to do it in Twig other than what you've done in the `if` part of your conditional.  Something like this should work:

```
{% if attribute(data, entry_name) is not defined and entry_total > 0 %}
    {% set data = data|merge({ (entry_name) : entry_total }) %}
{% else %}
    {% set data = data|merge({ (entry_name): 10 }) %}
{% endif %}
```